# How to play a video in HTML 5 by playlist already listed?

Tags: html, html5-video, playlist

I have a single code index.html like this:
I create the style, script and the video body.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>tes video</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
        #playlist {
        display:table;
    }
    #playlist li{
        cursor:pointer;
        padding:8px;
    }

    #playlist li:hover{
        color:blue;                        
    }
    #videoarea {
        float:left;
        width:1280px;
        height:720px;
        margin:10px;    
        border:1px solid silver;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
            $("#videoarea").attr({
                "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
                "autoplay": "autoplay"
                "type: video/mp4"
            })
        })
            $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        })
        })
</script>

<body>
    <video id="videoarea" controls="controls" src=""></video>

    <ul id="playlist">
        <li movieurl="kendrickdna.mp4">Dna</li>
        <li movieurl="kendrickhumble.mp4">Humble</li>
    </ul>
</body>
<html>
```

i want to create a simple playlist video in my html but the video doesn't appear, what i'm wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

syntax error here: "type: video/mp4".

it should be "type": "video/mp4".

you can see example here - [jsfiddle.net/kv9s9a0a/1](https://jsfiddle.net/kv9s9a0a/1/)

```
$("#playlist li").on("click", function(){
    $("#videoarea").attr({
    "src": $(this).data("movieurl"),
    "autoplay": true,
    "type": "video/mp4"
  });
});
```